# Zeppelin won't use the conf/zeppelin-site.xml file

Tags: docker, apache-zeppelin

I have started an apache/zeppelin:0.8.1 docker instance, and followed this manual to disable anonymous access: https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.8.1/setup/security/shiro_authentication.html

No matter what I try, Zeppelin site in its config page is not reading any changes in conf/zeppelin-site.xml

I even tried to modify the configuration file from a Zeppelin notebook, still no effect. 
zeppelin-site.xml permissions and ownership are set up same as in zeppelin-site.xml.template

cat conf/zeppelin-site.xml | grep -A3 -n anon

```
408:  <name>zeppelin.anonymous.allowed</name>
409-  <value>false</value>
410-  <description>Anonymous user allowed by default</description>
411-</property>
```

ls -la conf

```
drwxr-xr-x 1  503 root  4096 Jun 14 06:36 .
drwxr-xr-x 1  503 root  4096 Jun 14 07:18 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1  503 root  1326 Jan 16 01:45 configuration.xsl
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 46755 Jun 14 07:18 interpreter.json
-rw-r--r-- 1  503 root  2634 Jan 16 01:45 interpreter-list
-rw-r--r-- 1  503 root  1382 Jan 16 01:45 log4j.properties
-rw-r--r-- 1  503 root  1018 Jan 16 01:45 log4j_yarn_cluster.properties
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  5342 Jun 14 06:35 shiro.ini
-rw-r--r-- 1  503 root  5342 Jan 16 01:45 shiro.ini.template
-rw-r--r-- 1  503 root  5799 Jan 16 01:45 zeppelin-env.cmd.template
-rw-r--r-- 1  503 root  7910 Jan 16 01:45 zeppelin-env.sh.template
-rwxr-xr-x 1  503 root 20018 Jun 14 06:36 zeppelin-site.xml
-rwxr-xr-x 1  503 root 20017 Jan 16 01:45 zeppelin-site.xml.template
```

Then, as stated in manual i restarted Zeppelin:

```
bin/zeppelin-daemon.sh restart
```

which produced no effect on the configuration page:

```
Configurations
Shows current configurations for Zeppelin Server.
Note: For security reasons, some key/value pairs including passwords would not be shown.
name                         value
zeppelin.anonymous.allowed  true
```

Comment: Zeppelin can be configured by defining environment variables in `conf/zeppelin-env.sh` or by defining java properties in `conf/zeppelin-site.xml`. Note that if you have a `zeppelin-env.sh` file alongside your `zeppelin-site.xml` file, the `zeppelin-env.sh` will take priority. So is the mistake maybe by having an additional `zeppelin-env.sh` file in your `conf/` directory?

Comment: Thank you, Bajiro. I have went through the zeppelin-env.sh - it was all commented, will try to rename it to zeppelin-env.sh.template, or to find out how to specify the location of the zeppelin-site.xml
Thanks

Comment: Even if the `zeppelin-env.sh` file is completely commented out, it is read by zeppelin, so your `zeppelin-site.xml` is never considered by Zeppelin at all. Renaming it would be the most straightforward solution, yes!

Comment: that didn't help, but I have noticed that stopping zeppelin 
```bin/zeppelin-daemon.sh stop```
isn't affecting anything, web-app still works. Though, restarting it temporary throws http status 403

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolved by restarting the container. 
The original manual incorrectly states that it is sufficient with the zeppelin service restart.